# Was Kylo Ren's birth name homage to Obi-wan's?

Tags: character, star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* we learn that Han's and Leia's son, Kylo Ren, was born as Ben.

Now while in *A New Hope* Leia's message to Obi-wan called him as such, when Luke went to rescue her on the Death Star she called him Ben Kenobi

> **Leia:** You're who?
>   **Luke:** I'm here to rescue you. I've got your R2 unit. I'm here with Ben Kenobi.
>   **Leia:** Ben Kenobi is here! Where is he?

So was Kylo Ren's birth name homage Obi-wan's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Possibly, yes.**

Many fans know that when Disney bought Lucasfilm, the former canon was reconed to "Legacy" to make way for their new canon. What many fans didn't know is that Disney's new canon would continue to borrow from old canon--recontexualizing it within the new.

> In order to give maximum creative freedom to the filmmakers and also
>   preserve an element of surprise and discovery for the audience, Star
>   Wars Episodes VII-IX will not tell the same story told in the
>   post-Return of the Jedi Expanded Universe. **While the universe that
>   readers knew is changing, it is not being discarded.** Creators of new
>   Star Wars entertainment have full access to the rich content of the
>   Expanded Universe. **For example, elements of the EU are included in
>   Star Wars Rebels. The Inquisitor, the Imperial Security Bureau, and
>   Sienar Fleet Systems are story elements in the new animated series,
>   and all these ideas find their origins in roleplaying game material
>   published in the 1980s.**
>   http://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page

[image: Thrawn Rebels]

So one place where the former canon seems to be borrowing from is in regards to the new canon is from the former **Thrawn Trilogy**, which features characters such as Thrawn (now featured in *Star Wars Rebels* and with a new novel from Timothy Zahn) and the next generations of Skywalkers...

[image: Next Gen]

In the previous canon we had Hans' and Leia's children, twins Jacen and Jaina Solo whom were trained under Luke at his new Jedi school, along with his own son, Ben Skywalker (Named after Obi-Wan Kenobi). Jacen Solo eventually turns to the dark the side becoming Darth Caedus.

> "I'm just afraid of placing an extra one on his shoulders. Suppose I
>   named him Obi-Wan, as a salute to my old master? Would he think that
>   means that I want him to grow up to be a Jedi? Would he think he had
>   to live up to Ben's reputation?" ―Luke Skywalker[src]

[image: Jacen Ben]

So when we look at the former source material fans may be able to see blendings of the old characters into the new, **with Kylo Ren being Jacen Solo-esque, but with Ben Skywalker's first name** (and then one may speculate like the former, he too was also named after "Uncle Ben".) With Rey maybe having characteristics a little of Jaina, but probably more like Ben Skywalker (in initial personality), although she may not be a Skywalker at all...

[image: Jiana fights Jacen]

Jaina Solo may have been in part built into Jyn Erso, as Jyn has similar stylization to the former Jaina...

[image: Jaina Jyn]

Note: I would also like to point out that Ewan Mcgregor reprised his role by lending his voice to the flashback sequence in **The Force Awakens**. It could just be a fun easter-egg, but the context of his instructions to Rey, may imply that Obi-Wan could play a more substantial role either in pre TFA history and/or in upcoming films.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing I can cite from the films that would prove this beyond certainty but it is, in my and other fans opinion, fairly obvious by process of elimination - there are no other characters in the episodes with this name. Again, although it it not specified in any of the films it appears that Obi - Wan took on the name Ben after going into exile on Tatooine following the Emperors purge of the Jedi, he was a close friend of Bail Organa, adoptive father of Leia and was more or less directly responsible for Leia and Han's meeting aboard the Death Star, ultimately becoming as important a figure to Han as he was to Leia and Luke.

The Star Wars Wiki 'Wookieepedia' states on it's page on Kylo Ren "Ben Solo's namesake was that of the late Jedi Master Obi-Wan Kenobi, who went by the name of Ben Kenobi while in exile on Tatooine after the fall of the Jedi Order."

Link here - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kylo_Ren

Comment: Cheers for the edit Lars, but despite the improved grammer it does not change the fact that my answer appears to be absolute rubbish - with 83 views I would have thought that someone would have a definitive answer to this. The imminent release of 'The Last Jedi' and 'Battlefront 2' means that I am using the holiday period to re - immerse myself in my favourite fantasy world. I fucking LOVE Star Wars, including the prequels for which as a sad ass fan boy I must rank among their greatest apologists.